# Fractional Knapsack- explanation

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

The following algorithm is given:

```
Algorithm FractionalKnapsack(S,W):
Input: Set S of items, such that each item i∈S has a positive benefit b_i and a positive 
weight w_i; positive maximum total weight W
Output: Amount x_i of each item i ∈ S that maximizes the total benefit while not exceeding 
the maximum total weight W. 
for each item i∈S
    x_i<-0
    v_i<-b_i/w_i // value index of item i
w<-0
while w<W do
      remove from S an item i with highest value index // greedy choice
      a<-min{w_i,W-w} // more than W-w causes a weight overflow
      x_i<-a
      w<-w+a
```

According to my lecture notes:

To see that the fractional knapsack problem satisfies the greedy-choice property, suppose that there are two items $i$ and $j$ such that
$$x_i<w_i,\ \ \ x_j>0, \ \ \ \text{ and } v_i<v_j$$

Let $y=\min \{ w_i-x_i, x_j\}$.

We could then replace an amount  $y$ of item $j$ with an equal amount of item $i$, thus increasing the total benefit without changing the total weight.

Therefore, we can correctly compute optimal amounts for the items by greedily choosing items with the largest value index.

Could you explain me the idea of the proof?

Why does the following hold?

> We could then replace an amount  $y$ of item $j$ with an equal amount of item $i$, thus increasing the total benefit without changing the total weight.

I haven't understood it.

**EDIT**: Why do we deduce from the following:

We could then replace an amount  $y$ of item $j$ with an equal amount of item $i$, thus increasing the total benefit without changing the total weight.

that the fractional knapsack problem satisfies the greedy-choice property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It holds as, if the case assumed in the text (for contradiction) happens for a valid solution $x_1,\dots,x_n$ of the fractional Knapsack (where $x_k$ represents the fraction of the weight $w_k$ added to the Knpasack in that solution), then the following holds. You have a quantity $y>0$ of item $j$ in your solution (as $y \leq x_j$ by definition) and can still add at least a quantity $y$ of item $i$ to your knapsack before "using all the available quantity" of item $i$) (as $y \leq w_i - x_i$ by definition). So you can swap the quantity $y$ of item $j$ you have for the same quantity of item $i$ (formally decrease $x_j$ by $y$, and increase $x_i$ by $y$), this will still satisfy the constraints.

But the new overall value $V^\prime$ will become greater than the previous value $V$, as $V^\prime = V - y\cdot v_j +y\cdot v_i$; and $v_i > v_j$ (and $y>0$) by assumption.

Comment: Could you explain me further the following? $$$$
 You have a quantity $y>0$ of item $j$ in your solution.
$$$$
How can we be sure that $j$ should be contained in the knapsack? Or do we assume so?

Comment: You start with a solution $x_1,\dots, x_n$. The argument goes by showing that *if* there are items $i,j$ such that $x_i < w_i$, $x_j > $ and $v_j < v_i$, then this solution can be improved (and would be by the greedy algorithm). And since we have $x_j > 0$ and $x_i < w_i$, the quantity $y$ as defined is such that $x_j \geq y > 0$, so in particular there is a fraction $y$ of the weight $w_j$ in the solution we are trying to improve.

Comment: $v_j < v_i$ (I believe there is a typo in your lecture notes, it should be $v_j < v_i$) only ensures that the new solution has higher value.

Comment: So can the solution be improved because of the fact that w could replace several times the item $j$ with the item $i$? And can we say this, although  we are given no information about $w_i$ and $w_j$? $$$$
Also what does $y$ represent ? The current weight contained in the knapsack? Or something else?

Comment: The solution can be improved because by replacing a fraction $y$ (of weight $w_j$) of item $j$ by a fraction $y$ (of weight $w_i$) of item $i$, the value of the solution increases by $y(v_i-v_j)>0$. The new solution is strictly better. [$y$ represents a fraction of weight of item you add or remove from the Knapsack: $0< y\leq 1$; and you replace in the Knapsack a weight $yw_j$ of item $j$ by a weight $yw_i$ of item $i$.]

Comment: So $y$ is the current $x_j$ but we want to reduce it and increase $x_i$, right? But we cannot replace all the quantities of $j$ since $x_j>0$, right? $$$$
Could you explain me further why the solution increases  by $y(v_i-v_j)>0$ ?

Comment: Sorry, my above comment was wrong: $0< y \leq x_j$, and we replace in the knapsack a quantity $y$ of item $j$ (not $yw_j$). We would like to make $y$ as big as we want $x_j$, which is the maximum amount of item $j$ we can replace, since that's all there is in the solution), but it also has to be at most $w_i-x_i$, since *that* is the maximum quantity of item $i$ we can add to the solution. To see why the value increases by that amount, write what the solution value is in terms of $b_k$, $w_k$ and $x_k$'s. Then, use the defn of $v_k$ to express the value as a function of $x_k$, $v_k$'s only.

Comment: Can we replace all the quantities of item $j$, although we assume that it holds $x_j>0$ ?

Comment: I don't understand. Read the above: you cannot more that $w_i$ units of $i$, so you cannot replace all you have of item $j$ by the same quantity of item $i$ if this means you get more of $i$ than allowed. That's why $y$ is defined as the minimum of two quantities.

Comment: Why if we  then replace an amount $y$ of item $j$ with an equal amount of item $i$  would  the total benefit be increased without changing the total weight?

Comment: Because the weight you remove is $y$ (from iterm $j$) and the weight you had is $y$ (for item $i$), so the total weight is not changed. But the value changes by $-b_j\frac{y}{w_j}=-yv_j$ and $+b_i\frac{y}{w_i}=+yv_i$, as the objective function is $$ \sum_{k} b_k \frac{x_k}{w_k}.$$ But that means the total change of value is $-yv_j+yv_i = y(v_i-v_j)>0$.

Comment: Could you explain me further what you mean by: $$$$
But the value changes by $-b_j \frac{y}{w_j}=-y v_j$ and $+ b_i \frac{y}{w_i}=+yv_i$ ?

Comment: Look at the objective function. If you replace $x_j$ by $x_j-y$ and $x_i$ by $x_i+y$, how does the objective function change?

Comment: $$\sum_{i \in S} b_i \frac{x_i}{w_i}=b_1 \frac{x_1}{w_1}+ b_2 \frac{x_2}{w_2}+ \dots+ b_j \frac{x_j}{w_j}+ \dots+ b_i \frac{x_i}{w_i}+ \dots \\ = b_1 \frac{x_1}{w_1}+b_2 \frac{x_2}{w_2}+ \dots + b_j \frac{x_j-y}{\dots}+ \dots+ \frac{(y+x_i)}{ \dots}+ \dots$$

Do we have to change the denominators that corresponds to the items $i$ and $j$ ?

Comment: The only thing that changes is for the items $i$ and $j$, look at these two terms only to find out what changes between the objective value *before* and *after*.

Comment: It will be as follows, right? $$$$

$$\left( \sum_{i \in S} b_i \frac{x_i}{w_i} \right)^{\text{after}}= \sum_{i \in S} b_i \frac{x_i}{w_i}+y \frac{b_i}{w_i}-\frac{yb_j}{w_j}$$

Or am I wrong?

Comment: Indeed. So the difference between the two is what I wrote earlier, and is positive since $v_i>v_j$.

Comment: Isn't the difference equal to $y \left( \frac{b_i w_j-b_j w_i}{w_i w_j} \right)$ ?

Comment: I will stop answering now. Look at how $v_k$ is defined: $v_k=\frac{b_k}{w_k}$, so what I wrote and what you wrote are the *same*.

Comment: Oh yes, right... I am sorry.... So the difference is $y(v_i-v_j)$.
$$$$
From which fact do we deduce that  the fractional knapsack problem satisfies the greedy-choice property?